# How to right justify on the same line in LaTex?

Tags: layout, latex

I am trying to define the layout for a thesis approval page. So the institute layout has something like "name ..... affiliation _____" on one line where "..." is a horizontal fill and affiliation is right justified. How to create such a layout in Latex/Tex?

Comment: This is also useful for trying to (hack-ily) justify a partial line so it fills the entire column width. (Just insert \hfill between all the words on the line)

Answer (score 8):

Something like

```
name1\hfill affiliation1\\
name2\hfill affiliation2\\
```

Answer (score 0):

For just spreading things out [laalto nailed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928060/how-to-right-justify-on-the-same-line-in-latex/1928081#1928081): use `hfill`. If you want to get the intervening space filled with "..." or similar look at the way tables of contents are implemented in the standard classes.

You might also consider if the [`minitoc`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=minitoc) package can be made to work for you. Likewise the [`smalltableof`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=smalltableof) package.